# Nomes de cores não específicas

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Quando descrevendo características físicas em perfis biográficos vez ou outra tenho certa dificuldade em nomear cores pouco específicas.

Por exemplo: **Laranja**. Quase todo mundo sabe qual é a cor da laranja, mas usado num contexto de descrição, pode talvez ficar confuso, afinal temos a laranja... laranja, madurinha e temos ela ainda "verdinha" ou ainda laranjas que dificilmente chegam a ficar... laranja, ficando no máximo meio amarelada.

Se eu escrever que uma criatura, real ou fictícia, tem a pele laranja, algumas pessoas podem imaginar que a ela é [assim](http://0to255.com/FF7F00) (color wheel), [assim](http://www.0to255.com/FE5A1D) (tonalidade do San Francisco Giants) ou ainda [assim](http://www.0to255.com/636e21), se por acaso estiverem imaginando a casca da laranja pêra ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

> Se clicarem no link, a cor mencionada é aquela da barrinha mais saliente, quase no fim da página, que se destaca das demais ;-)

Recentemente esse... problema, ficou ainda pior pois precisei descrever o verde da maçã-verde, daí ficou, por exemplo, *Olhos: Verde Maçã-Verde*

Seria isso mesmo?

Comment: Poderia usar os nomes das tonalidades https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria:Tonalidades_de_laranja Tudo que o leitor precisaria fazer, se não souber, seria pesquisar os termos.

Answer (score 1):

Se se trata de literatura, então o que pode funcionar em cada caso específico depende bastante do contexto e das escolhas artísticas do autor.

Numa ficção científica, por exemplo, se poderia talvez até mencionar um código numérico para a cor, como os dos links:
- "Pele: laranja, #ff7f00".

Outra opção é se estender na descrição e usar mais adjetivos:
- "Sua pele era alaranjada, como que permanentemente iluminada pelo pôr do sol".

Mas, em geral, exatidão não combina bem com linguagem natural - por isso disciplinas mais técnicas costumam desenvolver jargões, estabelecer convenções e métricas. Isso não é necessariamente ruim. Há autores que inclusive brincam com a ambiguidade. E talvez se possa argumentar que a liberdade de interpretação é uma componente relevante da subjetividade da experiência da leitura.

Quanto à última pergunta, em particular, não vejo problema com o "Olhos: Verde Maçã-Verde", embora maçãs-verdes possam ter desde um verde mais escuro até um bastante amarelado, mesmo quase esbranquecido.

Comment: Beleza, então. É que fiquei meio receoso de parecer redundante. Vou só esperar um pouco mais e ver se alguém tem uma opinião diferente. E essa de estender a descrição com adjetivos até me ajuda no corpo do texto pra "encher linguiça" quando o material é pouco :p

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Você quase precisaria é de uma enquete. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As maçãs possuem diversas colorações, normalmente vermelhas. Dizer vermelho maçã provocaria dúvida. Agora, verde maçã já traz à mente aquele verde vivo único.

```
    Olhos: verde maçã.
```

Perfeito e não traz redundância.

A descrição de características pode ser mais sutil, como "pele alaranjada", ... ao invés de "pele laranja"!